# iSeries SQL - Getting and updating directory entries

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

We are looking to change the address part of all the users directory entries.  Has anyone accomplished anything similar?  Looking to see if there are any tables that hold this information, along the lines of returning and changing normal user profiles.  Even if there is a way to read through the directory entries in a CL and then run the RNMDIRE on each user.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the directory entries in this table qaok102a.

select * from qusrsys.qaokl02a;

Do not update the table directly and use system commands to make changes as you suggest in your post.

Comment: Scott:  That is perfect!  Thank you!!